# Integrating factor: renaming variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I'm having trouble following some math in a manuscript. The author is using an integrating factor to begin to solve a differential equation:

$$
dX(t)=[\mu(t)+b(t) X(t)]dt + \sigma(t)dB(t)
$$

by introducing the integrating factor

$$
e^{-\int_{}^{t} b(\tau) d\tau}
$$

$b()$ is not the derivative of $B()$. The given solution is:

$$
X(t)=\int_{0}^{t} e^{\int_{\tau}^{t} b(s) ds}\mu(\tau)d\tau+\int_{0}^{t} e^{\int_{\tau}^{t} b(s) ds}\sigma(\tau)dB(\tau)
$$

My questions is, why is this variable renaming allowed? I find something similar in the [wikipedia page for integrating factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor), but it's not clear to me why it's allowed (required?), or what the motivation is.

> We use this fact to simplify our expression to $$ \frac{d}{dx}(y
>  e^{\int_{s_0}^{x} P(s) ds}) = Q(x) e^{\int_{s_0}^{x} P(s) ds}  $$ We
>   then integrate both sides with respect to x, firstly by renaming x to
>   t, obtaining $$ y e^{\int_{s_0}^{x} P(s) ds} = \int_{t_0}^{x} Q(t)
>  e^{\int_{s_0}^{t} P(s) ds} dt + C $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrating factor can be chosen to be any one of infinitely many functions ($a$ can be anything): $$f_a(t)=\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau}\right)$$

If you're asking why I'm using $\tau$ there, it doesn't matter what I use there because it's a "[dummy variable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html)". In fact, another notation would allow me to write more simply:  $$f_a(t)=\exp\left({-\int_a^tb}\right)$$ However, if I used $t$ there and wrote something like $-\int_a^tb(t)\,\mathrm dt$, I might get confused because the $t$ on the inside that just tells me what function related to $b$ I'm integrating is a completely different thing than the $t$ on the outside which is the input of $f_a$.

Now, in the manuscript, the author does a nice little trick since a definite integral changes sign when you swap the limits of integration, so that $-\int_a^tb(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau=\int_t^ab(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau$.

If we want to substitute this into an even bigger expression, and $t$ is reserved we should use a third variable to avoid confusion, and write something like
$$\int_{0}^t\left(\exp\left(\int_s^ab(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\right)\right)\,\mathrm ds$$
However, for stylistic reasons, $\tau$ is traditionally kept closer to $t$/the outside, so we may write the following instead:
$$\int_{0}^t\left(\exp\left(\int_\tau^ab(s)\,\mathrm ds\right)\right)\,\mathrm d\tau$$

---

Now, the question is, why does your question have something more like: $$\int_{0}^t\left(\exp\left(\int_\tau^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds\right)\right)\,\mathrm d\tau$$
with $a$ changed into $t$?

It's because the solving of the differential equation goes something like:
$$\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)X'(t)=\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)b(t)X(t)+\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\text{stuff}$$
$$\Rightarrow\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)X'(t)-\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)b(t)X(t)=\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\text{stuff}$$
$$\Rightarrow\exp\left({-\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)X(t)+C_0=\int_0^t\exp\left({\int_\tau^a b(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\text{stuff}\,\mathrm d \tau$$
$$\Rightarrow X(t)+C_0=\int_0^t\exp\left({\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\exp\left({\int_\tau^a b(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\text{stuff}\,\mathrm d \tau$$
$$\Rightarrow X(t)+C_0=\int_0^t\exp\left({\int_a^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}+{\int_\tau^a b(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\text{stuff}\,\mathrm d \tau$$
$$\Rightarrow X(t)+C_0=\int_0^t\exp\left({\int_\tau^tb(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)\text{stuff}\,\mathrm d \tau$$

Comment: I had a hunch that this was a notation issue. I don't think there is a typo. I believe that in the manuscript, it is _t_ rather than _a_ because the integrating factor on the left side has been distributed into the integrals on the right side.  Does that make sense? If you have access, here is a reference if you're curious about the manuscript: Smith. Stochastic Dynamic Models of Response Time and Accuracy: A Foundational Primer. J. Math. Psychol. 44, 408–463 (2000). It's on page 420.

Comment: @Evan It makes perfect sense. I posted too quickly at first, and have edited my answer.